# Can an Interrupt handler write to a FIFO

Tags: linux, interrupt, fifo, irq

I have a thread that is waiting for events received on a FIFO.
Most of events are configuration events send from another thread in the same process.
I would like the thread also to be able to handle interrupt events by having the interrupt handler writing to the FIFO is that possible?

Any other suggestion instead of using FIFO is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. Using interrupt handlers is one of the newer ways of handling asynchronous I/O.

The more *typical* way of doing this, is with a select, poll, or Linux epoll command.

These are arguably a bit more preferred, because rather than "interrupting" your code when an event is available - you are able to handle events and return to the "poll" loop to get more events when you're *done* with the prior event. These mechanisms can wait on a number of different file descriptors at the same time, and return whichever one is available.

An interrupt handler is probably not what you want to do - because you don't necessarily want to be interrupted while processing one event, to know that another is ready.  If you did, you'd probably wind up queuing the request anyway for later handling - which is exactly what poll and epoll to to begin with.

If you're under Linux, "epoll" is the most optimum. If your not, (or want POSIX compliance), use "poll". "select" is an "older" method, and doesn't queue requests as well.